# Accordion - unclickable button

Tags: html, github

So recently I have been trying to dev my website. Because I didn't know much about HTML, I used github code, and cloned a template, which is jekflix by thiagorossner, you can find it [here](https://github.com/thiagorossener/jekflix-template).

So in the past few days I have been trying to add accordion to my website, and I used this link as reference: on [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp) and this instruction on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTdSW57--yM).

```js
var accordions = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
for (var i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
  accordions[i].onclick = function() {
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      // accordion is currently open, so close it
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      // accordion is currently closed, so open it
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
}

button.accordion:hover,{
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.accordion-content {
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  border-right: 1px solid whitesmoke;
  padding: 0 20px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion"> My name 2 </button>
<div class="accordion-content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Now what I got is a button that is not clickable, i.e. it does appear in the form of a button, but it does not respond to click.

For more information, here is my repository: https://github.com/dmtrung14/mathinspiration

What have I done wrong?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I put your code on snippet and it seems to work?

Comment: @A.Meshu I think his js code was all in one line so the part inside the if statement was commented out thats way it was not working.

Comment: @aerial301 i checked the initial question (before i changed title and added snippet) and i don't think that was the problem. Anyways let's wait for OP...

Comment: @A.Meshu No sir, even though it does work here, it doesn't work on my webpage. Furthermore, the original code didn't have scripts.js. Instead it had scripts.min.js, which is where I pasted the first snippet (the script) in. Could you clone it down and check if that was the problem?

Comment: Since your `.js` file in local, it's doesn't make any difference. I guess this is something else on your code.

Comment: I copied the exact same code to a folder of only index.html, styles.css, and scripts.js. It works to be honest, so I cannot think of a different cause than my code being in the wrong place